# What is a choice that is heavily favorable on one side?

Tags: phrases, expressions

A choice that is so favorable on one side that it somewhat forces you to pick the favorable one.

Example:

> "If you choose option A everyone will die or choose B to save everyone
>   (with a small chance of killing you)."

More specifically I'm talking about someone giving  you a choice (whether you like it or not), and while technically it is a choice, you feel like you don't actually have a choice (it was forced upon you), like my example.

Comment: A lop-sided choice.

Comment: You might be looking for something like a "forgone conclusion" but how will any real Answer not be about style or personal choice? If the Question was really about the language as such, why would it not respond to your thesauruses or search engines?

Comment: Either way, could you make that Question more clear? Could you post three or four of the options you considered, with the arguments for and against each?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite identical, but it's similar to a "Hobson's choice":

> A Hobson's choice is a free choice in which only one thing is offered. Because a person may refuse to accept what is offered, the two options are taking it or taking nothing. In other words, one may "take it or leave it". The phrase is said to have originated with Thomas Hobson (1544–1631), a livery stable owner in Cambridge, England, who offered customers the choice of either taking the horse in his stall nearest to the door or taking none at all.

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice))

Comment: It is very similar, but I'm looking for this, but while you technically have a choice your somewhat forced to pick one over the other (like my example).

Answer (score 0):

A choice that is "heavily favorable to one side" could be described as...

> **[one-sided](https://www.bing.com/search?q=one-sided&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)** : *adjective* unfairly giving or dealing with only one side of a contentious issue or question; biased or partial.

Answer (score -1):

This is only suitable when the person giving you such a chance stands to benefit from the situation: ***heads I win, tails you lose***

TFD:

> **[heads I win, tails you lose](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/heads+I+win%2C+tails+you+lose)**
>   A humorous statement meaning "No matter
>   what the outcome is, I still win or benefit."    Hyphenated if used as
>   a modifier before a noun.
>
> It's a classic heads-I-win-tails-you-lose setup: the oil companies
>   want individuals to lease their land with the promise of interest
>   paid—but only if there is a sizable discovery over a certain
>   threshold, failing which the individual is responsible for dealing
>   with a plot of land devastated by the drilling with nothing to show
>   for it.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.